# No breaks in the output

Tags: ruby

Just started Ruby yesterday (for the first time). And struggling a bit. Please help.

Here's the program:

```
print "What's your name?"
name = gets.chomp 
if name == "James"
    print "Someone loves you!"
else 
    print "Try again #{name}!"
end

print "How old are you?"
age = gets.chomp
if age <= "25"
    print "Boy, you are just a child"
elsif age >= "45"
    print "Shame on you old man, craddle snacher!"
end
```

The output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5WCz.png)

So my concern is; why is it not beginning from a new line after "Try again Jack". I would like all the questions and answers to start at a fresh line. Please help!

PS: Just ignore the content of the program. That was just something to keep myself motivated. I don't really mean to be offensive.

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code. Also, don't add useless tags.

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `print`.

Comment: Don't link to your code either. Links break. If you paste code your question will live forever.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need the minimum code in the question itself that demonstrates the problem. It's important to understand SO isn't a discussion list, it's an online reference book to help solve programming problems and your question just created a new article. Saying  "Just ignore the content of the program" doesn't fit what we do on SO. Please edit your question so it fits the SO model better. Please.

Comment: The Tin Man: Sorry, I asked! I said I was new and not aware of how things worked. You can't intimidate a new member like that. If you can't help, then just don't reply. Wouldn't that be better? Have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options, `print` with explicit linebreaks ( \n , also works on Windows), or `puts` which adds a linebreak if the string does not already ends with one. These two examples result in the same output:

```
print "Hello\nworld\n"

puts "Hello
world"
```

Comment: Lovely! Thanks a ton.

Comment: About your question: the code does not appear as code. Edit it, select the lines that are code and click the `{}` button, that should take care of it.

Comment: Ah! I see... Thank you again. And it is working now. :D